# C++ Fix the following code so that it will correctly recursively traverse a directory tree in order to find where a particular file is

Tags: class, templates

I have an assignment as following: Write a program will ask the user how many random numbers to generate. Then it will present a menu which has the options of Display, Average, Median, and Standard Deviation, Regenerate, and Quit. Without the use of a switch statement, or an if statements, or pointers to functions,  have the program execute the user's selection from the menu. (Note: Function pointers are not allowed!)

This is what I have so far:

```html
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <array>
#include <cmath>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

template <typename T> class wrapperclass
{
public:
    static T myclass;
};

class Display
{
public:
   static void myFunction(int random[], int num)
   {
       for(int i=0; i<num; ++i)
       {
           cout << random[i] <<endl;
       }
   }
};

class Average
{
public:
    static double myFunction(int random[], int num)
    {
        double avg = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<num; ++i)
        {
            avg += random[i];
        }
        return avg/num;
    }
};

class Median
{
public:
    static double myFunction(int random[], int num)
    {
        double mid = 0;
        if(num % 2 == 0)
        {
            mid = (random[num/2] + random[num/2-1])/2;
        }
        else
        {
            mid = random[num/2];
        }
        return mid;
    }
};

class StdDi
{
public:
    static double myFunction(int random[], int num)
    {
        double avg=0;
        double total=0;
        for(int i=0; i<num; ++i)
        {
            avg += random[i];
        }
        avg = avg/num;
        for(int i=0; i<num; ++i)
        {
            total += (avg-random[i])*(avg-random[i]);
        }
        total = total/num;
        return sqrt(total);
    }
};

class renerate
{
public:
    static void myFunction(int)
    {

    }
};

class quit
{
public:
    static void myFunction()
    {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
};


int main()
{
    int num = 0;
    int option = 0;
    map<int, class T> magic;
    cout << "How many random numbers would u like to generate? " << endl;
    cin >> num;
    int random[num];
    for(int i=0; i<num; ++i)
    {
        random[i] = rand() % 100 + 1;
    }
    cout << "   Menu"<<endl
         << "1. Display"<<endl
         << "2. Average"<<endl
         << "3. Median"<<endl
         << "4. Standard Deviation"<<endl
         << "5. Renerate"<<endl
         << "6. Quit"<<endl;
    cin >> option;
    cout<<wrapperclass<Average>::myclass.myFunction(random, num);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm about to directly pass the user input "option" into that "wrapperclass" like this "wrapperclass" so I can simply call the .myFunction since all classes have the same function name. but this won't work for c++ so is there any work around?

Comment: I guess you can take a look at template specialization, which could provides branch-like function.

Comment: You could create a vector of objects, where the object in the first element does Display, the second does Average, etc.

Comment: Also, can you change the question title? I presume it's a typo... it doesn't seem related to the question